# Insert that particular value changed record

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, insert

From the below code, if it displays 10 records and if the user changes '**Code**' or '**Number**' value of 2nd and 5th record, how to insert only that 2nd and 5th record in another separate table. But from my insert query i can insert all 10 records. But i need only two affected records to be inserted. Please help.

```
include('DB.php');
$sql="SELECT * FROM customer where customer_name='".$q."' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);
$row_count=1;
if($num_row>0)
{       
echo "<table >
<tr>
<th>S.No</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Code</th>
<th>Number</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$c_name=$row['c_name'];
$c_code=$row['c_code'];
$c_number=$row['c_number'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> $row_count.</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='c_name[]' id='c_name' value='$c_name' readonly /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='c_code[]' id='c_code' value='$c_code' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='c_number[]' id='c_number' value='$c_number' /></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $row_count++;
            } 
echo "</table>";
}
```

**INSERT:**

```
$c_name=$_POST['c_name'];
$c_code=$_POST['c_code'];
$c_number=$_POST['c_number'];

if(isset($c_code))
{                      
for($i=0;$i<count($c_code);$i++)
{
{
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer_table2(name,code,number)
VALUES ('$c_name[$i]','$c_code[$i]','$c_number[$i]')");
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use `INSERT`, use `UPDATE` to modify existing rows. If the values are the same, it won't have any effect.

Comment: No. I need to show in report of old and new record, so I am having two tables. First table will have old record, second table (customer_table2) will have only the updated records.

Comment: Before inserting, test whether the row already exists in the old table.

Comment: How will i do if i am inserting it in a different table?

Comment: Do a `SELECT` in the first table, see if it already exists. If not, add it to the new table.

Comment: Please give me a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `SELECT` query first, to see if the row is already in the original table. If not, add it to the new table.

```
$c_name=$_POST['c_name'];
$c_code=$_POST['c_code'];
$c_number=$_POST['c_number'];

if(isset($c_code))
{                      
    for($i=0;$i<count($c_code);$i++)
    {
        // Prevent SQL injection
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($c_name[$i]);
        $code = mysql_real_escape_string($c_code[$i]);
        $number = mysql_real_escape_string($c_number[$i]);
        $select = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM customer WHERE name = '$name' AND code = '$code' AND number = '$number'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select);
        if ($row['c'] == 0) {
            $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer_table2(name,code,number)
                                VALUES ('$name','$code','$number')");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample. But this inserts all records. But i need only 2nd and 5th record to be inserted since i change the value in that both records.

Comment: I'm not sure why that's happening. If you didn't change the values, the `SELECT COUNT(*)` should find the existing row, so `COUNT(*)` will be more than 0.

Comment: Is something removing those rows from the `customer` table before the user submits the form?

Comment: There is some mess within my code, i'll try to fix it. Thanks for the useful sample.